# Limit Ether balance on tests accounts

Tags: truffle

I have create a truffle project with this command:

```
truffle unbox react
```

I have looked at test/simplestorage.js and add a test:

```
contract("SimpleStorage", accounts => {
     it("my test", async () => {
         console.log(await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[1]));
     });
 });
```

I can see test accounts are credited with 100 Ether. Is there a way to choose how much ether i can put in each account test ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

100 Ether is the default amount held by Ganache accounts.

You can change it :

- If you use the Ganache desktop client, go to the parameter (in the right hand corner) > `Accounts & Keys`. Then change the `account default balance` field and click on the button `save and restart`.
- If you use the command line client (ganache-cli) you can use the tag `-e` to change the default test accounts balance.

Comment: I am launching tests with "truffle test" command. This is not ganache, this is a javascript EVM. And i want to set this limit in my test scenario because this limit depends on the tests i want to do